# How can I automatically restart charms after boot up

Tags: juju

Here is the case:

How can I automatically restart charms after boot up?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - as the "config changed" hook is run after a reboot of the machine. If the charm is well formed, during its installation/start phase it should plug in an upstart (sysvinit, et-al) job to start the service on the proper runlevels. Can you show me an example?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `@raboot command` cron job

in terminal `crontab -e`
it will open a cron job file where you can add jobs.

add a line with

```
@reboot "command you want with all switches needed"
```

without the "" that is.